# Как получить определенную ветку с удаленного сервера?

Tags: git, git-pull

Склонировал ветку master, потом сделал `git pull origin ветка`, но в ответ мне пришло следующее:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: По какому протоколу вы подключены? Если ssh то попробуйте через  [https](https://github.com/jkbrzt/cloudtunes/issues/23)

Comment: Это какую команду нужно написать?

Comment: [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200237/how-do-i-get-git-to-default-to-ssh-and-not-https-for-new-repositories) описывается как изменить эту настройку через команду или конфигурационный файл

Comment: а почему просто не сделать вначале `git branch -a`, запомнить имя, а потом сделать `git checkout имя` (при этом имя просто указывать, без origin и подобного)

Comment: `Склонировал ветку master` - нет, вы клонировали репозиторий. Ветка master просто выбирается по умолчанию.

Comment: @KoVadim автор вроде уже должен знать о таком способе, это было в прошлом вопросе...

Comment: Автор, а у вас точно не было опечатки в командах? Какой результат, если сделать просто `git pull`?

Comment: Если сделать git pull origin ветка, при этом мы будет находиться в другой ветке, то будет "слияние двух веток". Вряд ли это хочет вопрошающий.

Comment: @KoVadim да, этого он наверняка не хочет.

Comment: Если коротко, то используйте `git branch -a --list origin*`, `git checkout master`, `git pull origin XXX`, XXX -- branch.